# How to encode string so dialogue would show html links etc

Tags: android, html, string, android-alertdialog, encode

Everything works nicely if i keep the text with html links in the strings file and use:

```
View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.general_info, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(R.string.general_info_message);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setTitle(
            "General Information").setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alert = builder.create();
```

But if i change

```
textView.setText(R.string.general_info_message);
```

to

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.general_info);
    String general_info_message = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    final SpannableString s = 
               new SpannableString(general_info_message);
```

...

```
textView.setText(s);
```

and keep the text in .txt file in res/raw it just shows the text with all html tags but don`t interpret them

Comment: Got it work by Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(general_info_message);